# Compile Tensorflow in ubuntu18.04 with CUDA9.2 cuDNN7.1.4 but got error libtensorflow_framework.so, not found

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I want to compile tensorflow 1.9 with CUDA9.2 and cuDNN7.1.4.
But I always got error:

```
ERROR: /home/gratia/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1443:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:gen_audio_ops_py_wrappers_cc' failed (Exit 1)
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: warning: libcublas.so.9.2, needed by bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Uaudio_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: warning: libcudnn.so.7, needed by bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Uaudio_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: warning: libcufft.so.9.2, needed by bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Uaudio_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: warning: libcurand.so.9.2, needed by bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Uaudio_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)......
```

What should I do?

Comment: By the way, I can find these file in /usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64

Comment: Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH path set to include /usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64? /usr/local/cuda/lib64 will work also if /usr/local/cuda is a symlink to /usr/local/cuda-9.2

Comment: Yes, The LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/enviroment include /usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64. The cuda path setting in tensorflow of bazel was /usr/local/cuda-9.2 and i did not make symlink when i install cuda 9.2

Comment: Make sure the file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda-9-2.conf exist and list the directory /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib then run sudo ldconfig. This will update the cache of shared libraries. If you want you can run sudo ldconfig -v for more verbose output to verify the cuda files are found.